# How do I add a custom mob to Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

Basically decided to make my own mob, I have:

- Created my mob's entity class
- Created my mobs model class
- Drawn the model
- Added the function call for addMapping within the EntityList class

I'm stuck on what to do next. I've tried finding the code that deals with passive animal spawning in the world, however I can't seem to find it.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've made a [new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35011/modding) for a modding site on stackexchange, if you want to give it your vote. Can't hurt, even if someone answers your question here.

Comment: And do a search on "minecraft", you will find results on this site re modding that game.

Comment: World.java:2818 - during the tick method - SpawnerAnimals.performSpawning(this, spawnHostileMobs, spawnPeacefulMobs && worldInfo.getWorldTime() % 400L == 0L);

Answer (score 18):

Well I'm not going to write a whole tutorial (because I have limited time right now) but I will link you to some resources and give some tips.

Firstly if you are going to mod Minecraft in any way, you want to go to the modding wiki.

I had a look around the wiki, and found a [basic mob creation tutorial](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/Simple_Person_Mob).

There is a [massive mod creation tutorial here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/96862-creating-mods-modding-tutorials-21511/). You should have a skim through that

I picked out some individual tutorials that you might like-

- [Create a new mob (they call it NPC, same thing)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/96862-creating-mods-modding-tutorials-21511/page__st__40__p__1541537#entry1541537)
- [Controlling a custom mob's movement](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/96862-creating-mods-modding-tutorials-21511/page__st__640__p__2063738#entry2063738)

Now on to the model creation, this took me a while to find, but I found 3 modelling programs.

- [Techne](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/200676-modeler-techne/) - Allows you to create models, which will then be converted into Java code. has alot of user tutorials on how to create replicas of vanilla models (cows, endermen etc.)
- [MCModeller](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/297974-modelertool-mcmodeler-v11-mac-gui-fixed/) - Quite simple GUI, live preview. Coded in Java
- [FMCModeller](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/247851-modeler-fmcmodeler-v026-minecraft-models-in-a-flash/) - GUI is not as simple, but it looks extremely professional with 2 view, one for the spritesheet and one for displaying the model live (which you can rotate etc.). Coded in Flash.

For the passive animal spawning code, I suggest you download [Minecraft Coders Pack MCP](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases), and search through the source files. The way I first found how to mod the terrain generator, was searching the source directory for the blockID I was modding. I suggest you search for terms like "spawn" and "entity".

You must understand however, that when Mojang releases modding support, this will be much easier, so be prepared to change your code. Also with the newest Adventure Updates, Mojang is constantly changing the code.